# Grab console output under AQTime

Tags: aqtime

I am trying to profile Windows (x64) console application using AQTime. Seems Performance Profiler is fine but when I run it under Allocation Profiler the application exits immediately. There is some console output but the application window is closed so fast so it is impossilbe to read.

- There are no errors in AQTime event log
- There are no errors in Windows event log
- Console redirection ( > some_file.txt) in Run Parameters does not work

How to troubleshoot such problem? **It there any way to tell AQTime to leave the console window open?**

Comment: AQTime version 6.21.400.64

Comment: You have a very old version of the tool. Perhaps, it has problems working on your version of OS. Try using an older OS. Also, you can make use of the AQtime Troubleshooter and perhaps it can help. http://support.smartbear.com/about-troubleshooter